# Many (many) SQL JOINs vs Multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, relational-database

I'm here to ask a question that many of you have already ask yourselves, I suppose. I am creating a PHP website, and everything has been running smoothly until I decided to populate my database with some test data (real data, which when the application starts being used for real, is going to be even bigger). Most of the things still work fine, but one particular (and really important) feature started having execution times of three to four seconds, and most of these time is spent in the MySQL server.

Here's the deal: I'm building an application for a school, and it needs to have all the schedules and lessons for every day, every person, every room, every class. The structure of the database is done, the indexes are created, etc... The problem is that since all this data is relational (and can be spread across many tables) one query to get them all might look like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, etc
FROM schedules AS su
LEFT JOIN schedules_lessons AS sul
    ON sul.ID_SCHEDULE = su.ID
LEFT JOIN schedules_lessons_teachers AS sult
    ON sult.ID_LESSON = sul.ID
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON u.ID = sult.ID_TEACHER
LEFT JOIN schedules_periods AS sup
    ON sup.ID_SCHEDULE = su.ID
LEFT JOIN schedules_periods AS sulp
    ON sulp.ID_SCHEDULE = sul.ID_SCHEDULE AND sulp.period = sul.period
LEFT JOIN schools AS s
    ON s.ID = su.ID_SCHOOL
LEFT JOIN schools_buildings AS sb
    ON sb.ID_SCHOOL = s.ID
LEFT JOIN schools_rooms AS sr
    ON sr.ID = sul.ID_ROOM
LEFT JOIN schools_classes AS sc
    ON sc.ID = sul.ID_CLASS
```

Yeah, that's a lot of joins, I know. My question is: how should I get the best balance between the number of joins & the number or queries? Because I feel like this could be really improved, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Most of the tables will have the records count under 200, only the lessons table can have lots more. The minimum is something near 5k, and the maximum can be something like 30k, or more.

Comment: Without knowing your schema is not easy to give advices, but guessing it from your query, it seems there's nothing wrong there. To improve performances, have you correctly indexed all the relevant fields (all the foreign keys in your example) in all tables? Also, the second join with `schedules_periods AS sulp` seems redundant, just change the first join to `LEFT JOIN schedules_periods AS sup ON sup.ID_SCHEDULE = su.ID AND sup.period = sul.period`. About the query length, well you could use some views in order to make your queries shorter. There's nothing wrong in a well normalized DB.

Comment: stuff like this is where nosql shines.. that is hideous to look at.

Comment: @Eggplant Hi. Well, the truth is that the (redundant) query was a little trick that I use to make the ordering work. It's a little hard to explain. This is because the periods are schedule-specific, which means they are different for every schedule. So I did not only want to select the period that corresponds to the lesson, but also the ones that correspond to the whole schedule, while stil ordering the lessons by the start of their period. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this information and the tables are properly indexed, then your join query should be a very reasonable way to extract the data.  You can check to see if the indexes are being used by adding `explain` before the query.

When you say "most of [the] time is spent in MySQL server", are you taking into account that returning thousands of rows takes time?  You might try doing the same query, but replacing the `select . . .` with `select count(*)` to see what the underlying query performance is.  Another way would be to add `order by <something> limit 1` to the existing query -- the `order by` has to fully process the query before returning a result.

Finally, if this only started to be a problem, what has changed since it worked the way you want it to?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Well, this started since i inserted some real data into the database (creating those 4k+ rows). Also, I've checked the phpMyAdmin for every table, anc checked the indexes and they are all created for those fields. Also, when I said the query time, I actually only measured the time taken by the query function, before fetching the results. Also, following your advice of using the count(*) dropped the execution time to something like 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a database expert, but maybe it makes sense to only query the information from the database you currently need in your app or web page.
This should be possible in a reasonably short time, I guess.
The rest can then be queried from the database when it's actually needed.

Please note that the database server is building one big table in memory where all the joins are merged. If your server has too less memory, it might have difficulties to build this table. (Although that might probably not be the case in your scenario...)

Answer (score 0):

As much as possible you should let the database handle the joins and avoid making more queries than necessary. In theory this should be optimal. Your query seems fine provided all the join fields are indexed.
The stated volumes are nothing spectacular and response times should be fine (once again provided all indexes are created).
Bear in mind that you should rarely if ever have queries that return many records (an exception being reports of course) - in the application you should control this with pagination.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Well, the truth is that there is pratically no way to reduce what I'm querying to the database, since I already only query the lessons that belong to the schedule that the user is requesting. It might end up returning 30 lessons max. :)

Comment: Hi, based on your information: 30 records returned and execution time > 1 second I'd say there might be an index missing, or your database is very slow. You should check the execution plan.